# Conversão de arquivo de audio .Wav para .Mp3

Tags: c#

Gostaria de auxilio, tenho a seguinte situação.

Possuo uma aplicação Web na qual retornar um arquivo de áudio de acordo com as solicitações. Porem(Acredito eu) por esses áudios serem do formato .wav eu não consegui escuta-los, porém ao retornar uma gravação .mp3 foi possivel escuta-la normalmente.

Tentei implementar alguma forma de converter os arquivos .wav para .mp3 utilizando o NuGet package NAudio com o código abaixo porém não obtive sucesso.

```
private void ConvertWavMP3(string wavFile)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var wavRdr = new WaveFileReader(wavFile))
            using (var mp3Writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(wavFile.Replace(".wav", ".mp3"), wavRdr.WaveFormat, 128))
            {
                wavRdr.CopyTo(mp3Writer);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error converting wav to mp3.", "CONVERSION ERROR");
        }
    }

private static void ConvertMp3ToWav(string mp3File)
{
    try
    {
        using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3File))
        {
            //using (WaveStream pcmStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1), reader))
            using (WaveStream pcmStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader))
            {
                WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(mp3File.Replace(".mp3", ".wav"), pcmStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error converting mp3 to wav.", "CONVERSION ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque o código que você usou para a sua tentativa inicial, que ajudaremos.

Comment: Perdão acabei salvando a pergunta sem o código! Alterado!

Comment: O bit rate está errado, use `LamePreset.ABR_128` no lugar de `128`, em `using (var mp3Writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(wavFile.Replace(".wav", ".mp3"), wavRdr.WaveFormat, 128)) { ... }`

Comment: Creio que essa abordagem pode funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22889091/4312593

Comment: @MarceloUchimura como eu retorno o arquivo convertido ?

Comment: @VictorAugusto, você tá usando qual versão de ASP.NET?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura 4.5.2

Answer (score 2):

O bit rate está errado, use `LamePreset.ABR_128` no lugar de `128`, em

```
using (var mp3Writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(wavFile.Replace(".wav", ".mp3"), wavRdr.WaveFormat, 128)) { ... }
```

Para devolver um streaming MP3 a partir do nome do arquivo, faça assim: adicione um ashx e implemente

```
public class MeuHandlerDeMp3 : IHttpHandler
{
    private const string CAMINHO_SERVIDOR = @"C:\MP3";

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string nomeArq = context.Request.QueryString["f"];
        string caminho = Path.Combine(CAMINHO_SERVIDOR, nomeArq);

        if (File.Exists(caminho))
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
            context.Response.WriteFile(caminho);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Daí, no browser, chame o ashx assim: na barra de URL do browser, digite `http://www.meusite.com.br/meuhandlerdemp3.ashx?f=Metallica%20%2d%20Hero%20Of%20The%20Day.mp3`

EDIT: no iOS/Safari, tente criar uma página aspx com uma tag `<audio>`:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="meuhandlerdemp3.ashx?f=Metallica - Hero Of The Day.mp3" />
</audio>
```

EDIT 2: seu arquivo .wav deve ser muito antigo; fazer assim para convertê-lo para formato PCM:

```
private void ConvertWavMP3(string wavFile)
{
    try
    {
        using (var wavRdr = new WaveFileReader(wavFile))
        using (var pcmReader = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(wavRdr))
        using (var mp3Writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(wavFile.Replace(".wav", ".mp3"), pcmReader.WaveFormat, 128))
        {
            pcmReader.CopyTo(mp3Writer);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error converting wav to mp3.", "CONVERSION ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito funcionou perfeitamente ,só uma duvida para outros arquivos, não áudios como funciona da mesma forma?

Comment: Sim. Só troque o content type, dependendo do caso do arquivo.

Comment: Cara fiz um teste aqui no navegador no IOS e o arquivo não abriu, tem alguma ideia do que possa ser ? no Android funcionou normal

Comment: Acho que tem que estar dentro da tag `<audio>`

Comment: Aqui https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3040776 tem um thread dizendo que o content type do MP3 tem que ser `audio/x-mpeg`, no Safari.

Comment: Arquivo de audio original do repositorio é .wav não precisaria converte-lo ?

Comment: Precisa; converta-o com o código que você fez, usando minhas ressalvas, salvando em uma pasta. E, depois no handler ashx, pegue dessa mesma pasta.

Comment: Estou com o seguinte erro na hora de escrever o novo arquivo "Unsupported encoding format ALaw
Parameter name: format"

Comment: Editei a resposta.